# KNN edges / graph

Tags: r, graph, knn, hierarchical-clustering, minimum-spanning-tree

I have created the dissimilarity matrix for my data. I am trying to get the set of edges results from the `KNN` method. I have read that `KNN` is a supervised learning method. So from all the literature that I have been reading there is this training set and testing set then the algorithm predicts the classification of the test data. But what I'm after is not the classification (or result) but the set of edges which resulted from say `3-NN` method.

Does `R` have a function for `KNN` wherein I can get the edges instead of the classification output?

Also, does `R` have a built-in function to plot the graph/tree? I've been searching but all I can see are the basic plots. Maybe I'm searching the wrong way.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The edges your are talking about are simply the decision boundaries of your KNN classifier. KNN assigns a label for each sample of your dataset but can classify any point of your input space.

I will assume your input space has 2 dimensions.

The easiest way to approximate these boundaries would be to classify an evenely spaced grid of points assigning a color for each unique label. The boundaries are then the intersection between color zones.